# Angular Google Maps (AGM): getting the Api Key in the app.module

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I'm using [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-maps.com/) (ngm) for my Angular 6 applications. I want to store the api key in my config.json file and read it through a config service. The config service is already called in the APP_INITIALIZER as follows:

### app.module.ts:

```
  export function initializeData(appConfig: AppConfig, authService: AuthService, localeService: LocaleService, clientConfigService: ClientConfigService, globalService: GlobalService) {
  return () => {
    try {
      return appConfig.load().then(() => {
        return Promise.all([authService.authenticateClient(), //...some other configs...//]).then((results) => {
          return Promise.resolve();
        }, (err) => {
          return Promise.reject(err);
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
    }

  }
}

@NgModule({
providers: [
 AppConfig,
 {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeData,
      deps: [AppConfig, AuthService],
      multi: true
    },
],
imports: [
 AgmCoreModule.forRoot(),
]
});
```

I have also imported the AgmCoreModule. I know I have to write a provider to lazy load the api key as follows:

```
{ provide: LAZY_MAPS_API_CONFIG, useClass: GoogleMapConfigService },
```

Inside the GoogleMapConfigService class, I have to access the API KEY from the config as: `AppConfig.settings.googleMapsApiKey;`

The issue is - appconfig.settings is undefined because the app_initializer may not have been executed when the `GoogleMapConfigService` is called.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare AppConfig  within the 'providers' like this:

```
providers: [
 AppConfig,
 {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeData,
      deps: [AppConfig, AuthService],
      multi: true
    },
]
```

Comment: It is already part of the providers. I have updated my code above.

Comment: Have you declared your api key within load() function of appConfig?

Comment: Yes, load() reads the entire config file and load them. I think GoogleMapConfigService gets called before the load() method executes.